# Eloqua integration via REST API using JAVA

Tags: java, oracle, api, rest, eloqua

Contact standard fields like First Name, Last Name and Email Address have been set via java and integrated using Rest API.

- Could you please guide me in creating custom objects and custom fields via java using REST API?
- I can create the same in .NET how to do the same in java?

.NET code is below:

```
var customObject = new CustomObject
{
    id = -10001,
    name = "Disruption",
    fields = new List<CustomObjectField>
    {
        new CustomObjectField
        {
            name = "FlightNumber",
            dataType = Enum.GetName(typeof(DataType), DataType.text),
            type = "CustomObjectField"
        },
        new CustomObjectField
        {
            name = "FlightDate",
            dataType = Enum.GetName(typeof(DataType), DataType.text),
            type = "CustomObjectField"
        },
        new CustomObjectField
        {
            name = "DisruptionType",
            dataType = Enum.GetName(typeof(DataType), DataType.text),
            type = "CustomObjectField"
        },
        new CustomObjectField
        {
            name = "EmailAddress",
            dataType = Enum.GetName(typeof(DataType), DataType.text),
            type = "CustomObjectField"
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class representing your data with Java (using ArrayList for JSON arrays):

For your field:

```
public class customObjectField {
private String FlightNumber;
private String FlightDate;
...
}
```

For your object:

```
public class customObject {
private int id;
private String name;
private arrayList<customObjectField> fields;
}
```

Instantiate then serialize with gson. Then post the String.